# R Programming : Fastest way to find common elements among 2 arrays (including duplicates)?

Tags: r

I would like to find the common elements (including duplicates) among 2 arrays. Which would be the fastest way to achieve this? (I would not mind utilizing a package as long as it is fast)

[I've already checked out intersect() but it does not include duplicates]

[The code I'm using now is -

```
commonelements <- function(a, b) {

test <- c(a,b)
test <- test[duplicated(test)]
test[duplicated(test)]
}
```

Any way to make this faster? I may have to invoke this function millions of times.
]

Example,
Array 'A' = (1,2,2,2,3,4)
Array 'B' = (1,2,2,4,5,6)

I would like to get an array 'C' = (1,2,2,4)

[NOTE: Arrays would not always be sorted]

[EDIT : I am not specifically bothered about the order of the elements in array 'C'. I just need the length of array 'C']

Comment: Are you currently doing this in a way that you think is too slow? If so, share that code in your question. Put together an example that is representative of your data so that we can compare timings with your method. I'm sure doing it in R will always be faster than doing it by hand.

Comment: So how do you want to display duplicates? Your question is unclear since you didn't include sample data and expected output.

Comment: I just want opinions on what could possibly be the fastest way. Never said i'm doing it too slow. Thanks for your tremendous insight.

Comment: I've added on example for you :]

Comment: Will the lists always be sorted?

Comment: Are you talking about `array` objects as defined in R or vectors? Your example looks like vectors.

Comment: Lists would not always be sorted. Crap. My bad. What I meant was a vector of integers.

Comment: When running your function with the sample data, the output is `[1] 2 2 2`

Comment: So in your desired output `c(1,2,2,4)` is it correct that 2 only occurs twice, because that's the maximum frequency it appears in both vectors? You didn't explain that well.

Comment: Yeah thats the reason why. To be fair, I thought that was implied.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's the fastest possible, but this gets the job done.

```
my.array <- array(1:24, dim=c(3,4,2))
my.array2 <- array(5:28, dim=c(3,4,2))
my.array[my.array%in%my.array2]
```

Comment: Will this work for all cases? That is, if one array is longer than the other?

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output as specified in the question. Using the sample data, the output of `A[A %in% B]` is `[1] 1 2 2 2 4` (note 3 times 2)

Answer (score 1):

Edit after many comments and some clarification of expected output:

```
A <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4)
B <- c(1,2,2,4,5,6)

unlist(sapply(intersect(A, B), function(x) rep(x, min(sum(B == x), sum(A == x)))))
#[1] 1 2 2 4
```

And to make it a function as in the question (according to the latest edit only the length of the output is required):

```
commonelements <- function(A, B){
   length(unlist(sapply(intersect(A, B), function(x) rep(x, min(sum(B == x), sum(A == x))))))
}

commonelements(A, B)
[1] 4
```

#### Benchmark

```
set.seed(2014)

A <- sample(1:20, 100, TRUE)
B <- sample(1:20, 100, TRUE)

baptiste <- function(A, B) {
  a <- as.data.frame.table(table(A))
  b <- as.data.frame.table(table(B))

  coincidences <- merge(a, b, by.x="A", by.y="B")
  rle <- structure(list(lengths=apply(coincidences[,-1], 1, min),
                        values = as.numeric(coincidences[,1])), 
                   class="rle")
  return(inverse.rle(rle))
}

beginner <- function(A, B){
  unlist(sapply(intersect(A, B), function(x) rep(x, min(sum(B == x), sum(A == x)))))
}

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(baptiste(A, B), beginner(A, B), times = 50, unit = "relative")

Unit: relative
          expr     min      lq  median       uq      max neval
baptiste(A, B) 13.9784 12.4557 11.5562 11.71972 60.71423    50
beginner(A, B)  1.0000  1.0000  1.0000  1.00000  1.00000    50
```

Comment: This does not include duplicates

Comment: I would argue that that depends on what the OP means by "including duplicates". If any of the elements is duplicated several times in array1 and also present in array2, it will show up here, so one could say it is "included". If he wants a frequency count per common element, that's a different question, I would say.

Comment: It won't show up here. For `my.array <- array(c(1:23,5), dim=c(3,4,2))`
 `my.array2 <- array(c(5:27,5), dim=c(3,4,2))`
`intersect(my.array, my.array2)` yields
`5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23`, vs `5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23  5` which the other answer displays. You're right that this is a different question, however, since the first solution would give different answers for set A containing three 5s, vs set B containing three 5s, which is probably not desired, but we can't know because it's a poorly worded question.

Comment: I've re-worded the question. Check it out.

Comment: Ah, ok, so neither answer works. I'll solve this after work (in 4 hours) if nobody else has by then.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this,

```
A = c(1,2,2,2,3,4)
B = c(1,2,2,4,5,6)


a <- as.data.frame.table(table(A))
b <- as.data.frame.table(table(B))

coincidences <- merge(a, b, by.x="A", by.y="B")
rle <- structure(list(lengths=apply(coincidences[,-1], 1, min),
               values = as.numeric(coincidences[,1])), 
               class="rle")
inverse.rle(rle)
```

Timing with larger samples (adapted from beginneR)

```
A <- sample(1:2000, 100000, TRUE)
B <- sample(1:2000, 100000, TRUE)

Unit: relative
           expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 baptiste(A, B)  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000    50
 beginner(A, B) 23.08864 22.23251 21.65671 20.82651 13.88881    50
```

Comment: How would you turn that into the desired output `c(1,2,2,4)`?

Comment: @beginneR inverse.rle, see edit

Comment: The OP wrote that he might have to apply the function a million times, while it is not clear, how large A and B would be. After running my benchmark again with times = 10000 it seems my solution is faster for more replications while yours is faster for larger A and B

Comment: i know, i was just teasing ;)

Comment: Alright :) Anyway, it seems there is no fully vectorized solution to this problem (yet).

Comment: By the way, the size of A and B would be in the hundreds at most.

Comment: @user2500871 So, is your question solved by now?